Prevent state object from being persisted across sessions
I'm developing a VS Code extension that provides a Webview Panel and a Webview View. The Webview View acts as a Menu (henceforth referred to as "Menu") for the Panel and shows a "START" button.
When the "START" button is clicked, the Panel starts to show some long running process (like the catcoding sample). As long as this process is running, I want the Menu to show a "STOP" button - even if it is hidden and shown again.
For performance reasons, I don't want to use retainContextWhenHidden here. Instead I use the getState() and setState() methods provided by the VS Code API.
This works fine with only one problem:
If I close the VS Code window while the cat is coding (button shows "STOP") and reopen it again, the state of the previous session is restored (the button still shows "STOP instead of "START"). In this case, I want the state to be destroyed so that the user is presented the default Menu UI ("START") at startup.
I tried the following to fix this but none of it worked:

Post a corresponding message from the menu provider to the webview using postMessage() and handle it with setState(undefined). As trigger I tried the provider's onDidDispose() event and the extension.ts' deactivate() method (the latter is called when the window gets destroyed).
According to the API documentation, the state is destroyed when the webview panel is destroyed. So I tried to destroy the menu's view inside the extension.ts' deactivate() method using either

vscode.commands.executeCommand('<VIEW_NAME>.removeView') or
vscode.commands.executeCommand('setContext', '<VIEW_NAME.show>', false) to not fulfill the view's when condition inside package.json.



but it didnt't work in this place. Somewhere I read, that the VS Code API is not functioning properly inside the deactivate() method anymore as the renderer stops working when the window gets closed.
Does anyone know a solution to prevent the state object from being persisted across sessions?
